# 3 fingers long press in android with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, touch, touch-event

I am implementing functionality for my android application. And the functionality of the android application is described below.

Inside the `override fun onTouchEvent` function, I have got a three-finger tap. Now I want a long touch for three fingers. Which is I am not able to get it. Please let me know, May I trigger some task if 3 fingers tapped for 2 or 3 seconds (As Per requirement). Below is the code for the three-finger tap.

```
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    return if (event != null) {
        if (event.pointerCount > 1) {
            isDoubleFinger = true
            if (event.pointerCount == 3 && event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
                if (toggleSwitch.isChecked) {
                    //TODO MY TASK IS EXECUTING FOR THREE FINGER TAP
                } else {
                    setSnackBar(IConstant.MESSAGE.WARNING_PLAY_SWITCH)
                }
            }
        }
        true
    } else {
        super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

`TODO MY TASK IS EXECUTING FOR THREE FINGER TAP`

At the above line, I want the functionality should execute after long press. Any help will be markable as positive answer. Please help me to get out from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Handler with postDelayed 2 to 3 seconds whenever 3 pointers identified in onTouch MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN.
In MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP cancel the handler. If your hander does not cancel until your specified time then you can treat it as 3 fingers long press.

Comment: I tried this, But When I release the screen or whenever I pick my finger up then no event is triggering.